# How to apply data triggers on image based on entry

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have one entry and a image, as initial load of page i want to show close.png image, after entry is focus or user type anything in entry i want to show searchingicon.png image.

```xml
<Entry x:Name="MainSearchPage"/>
    
<Image Grid.Row="0" Source="close.png" Style="{DynamicResource EntryIcons}" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" Aspect="AspectFit">    
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainSearchPage},Path=Text.Length}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="searchingicon.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code to do that.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Source="searchingicon.png" Style="{DynamicResource EntryIcons}" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" Aspect="AspectFit">
           
            <Image.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger TargetType="Image">
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainSearchPage}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="false"/>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainSearchPage}, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="close.png" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger TargetType="Image">
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainSearchPage}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="false"/>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MainSearchPage}, Path=Text.Length}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="close.png" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
```

You just want to show close.png in two conditions:

1. The entry is unfocused and the entry's text length is 0, this is what the second `<MultiTrigger>` does.
2. The page is initial load (means the entry's text is null) and the entry is unfocused, this is what the first `<MultiTrigger>` does.